# 2 JPanels in the same location using Jigloo Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My problem is that I need to make a GUI that, on startup, displays a login screen, then, when the user succesfully logs in, displays a different screen. I've visited other questions on both this board and on others, and on all of them, the general consensus is that instead of using two different, JFrames, I should use 2 JPanels in the same JFrame. When a user logs in, the first JFrame, asking for log in details, will have its visibility set to false and the second JFrame's visibility will become True. The problem I'm having here is that I can't seem to place 2 JPanels on the same location. I'm using Jigloo to work on Swing. Whenever I place the second JPanel and set its visibility to false, it's size becomes 0,0. I tried putting components on the second panel, then setting my preferred size and then switching the visibility to false, but both panels disappeared during executionm despite the first frame's visibility still being true and being the proper size. Help please!

Comment: *"the general consensus .. When a user logs in, the first JFrame, asking for log in details, will have its visibility set to false and the second JFrame's visibility will become True."*  That is not the general consensus on any site worth paying attention to.  Use a `CardLayout`.  As an aside.. do you have a question?  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered a similar question wherein you've multiple panels within single JFrame.. and based on user action performed panels are replaced

[Can't seem to get .remove to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381202/cant-seem-to-get-remove-to-work/16381838#16381838)

To skin the program based on your query:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JPanel componentPanel = null;   
    private JPanel loginPanel = null;    
    private JLabel loginLabel = null;    
    private JPanel optionPanel = null;
    private JLabel optionLabel = null; 
    private JButton loginButton = null;

    public JPanel getComponentPanel()
    {
       if(null == componentPanel)
       {
           componentPanel = new JPanel();
           GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
           componentPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

           GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
           constraint.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

           loginPanel = new JPanel();           
           constraint.gridx = 0;
           constraint.gridy = 0;
           loginPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           loginPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           loginPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           loginPanel.setBorder(
                   BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

           loginLabel = new JLabel("Login Panel");
           loginPanel.add(loginLabel);
           componentPanel.add(loginPanel, constraint);

           optionPanel = new JPanel();         
           constraint.gridx = 0;
           constraint.gridy = 0;
           optionPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           optionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           optionPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
           optionPanel.setBorder(
                   BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

           optionLabel = new JLabel("Option Panel");
           optionPanel.add(optionLabel);
           componentPanel.add(optionPanel, constraint);

           loginButton = new JButton("Login");
           constraint.gridx = 0;
           constraint.gridy = 1;
           loginButton.addActionListener(this);
           componentPanel.add(loginButton, constraint);
       }       
       return componentPanel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        loginPanel.setVisible(false);
        loginButton.setEnabled(false);
        optionPanel.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Main main = new Main();

        frame.setTitle("Simple example");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setContentPane(main.getComponentPanel());

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically what you've to do once user perform the login action, is, set the visibility of login panel to false (or remove this panel if not to be used in your program afterwards) and set the visibility of option panel to true.. keep one thing in mind that the location (i.e. gridx = 0 and gridy = 0) is same for both of these panels (login and option panels)